# Find rows in dataframe with maximum values grouped by values in another column

Tags: r

I would like to solve this problem in R without using SQL.

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Sure, I could use sqldf to do it, but there must be a cool apply method in R to do it, too?

Comment: I don't know what "distinct" does, but `x[which.max(x$var),]` does the other part.

Comment: cool -- thanks!  I'd never used which.max. nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Setup data** First read in the data:

```
Lines <- "id  home  datetime  player   resource
1   10   04/03/2009  john    399 
2   11   04/03/2009  juliet  244
5   12   04/03/2009  borat   555
3   10   03/03/2009  john    300
4   11   03/03/2009  juliet  200
6   12   03/03/2009  borat   500
7   13   24/12/2008  borat   600
8   13   01/01/2009  borat   700
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$datetime <- as.Date(DF$datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

**1) base - by** There are many ways to process this using various packages but here we will show a base solution first:

```
> do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$home, function(x) x[which.max(x$datetime), ]))
   id home   datetime player resource
10  1   10 2009-03-04   john      399
11  2   11 2009-03-04 juliet      244
12  5   12 2009-03-04  borat      555
13  8   13 2009-01-01  borat      700
```

**1a) base - ave** and a variation (also only using the base of R):

```
FUN <- function(x) which.max(x) == seq_along(x)
is.max <- ave(xtfrm(DF$datetime), DF$home, FUN = FUN) == 1
DF[is.max, ]
```

**2) sqldf** and here it is using sqldf just in case:

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("select id, home, max(datetime) datetime, player, resource 
+        from DF 
+        group by home")
  id home   datetime player resource
1  1   10 2009-03-04   john      399
2  2   11 2009-03-04 juliet      244
3  5   12 2009-03-04  borat      555
4  8   13 2009-01-01  borat      700
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not use SQL as well, so I would do it in this way.

1)

```
df <- read.table("your file", "your options") # I leave this to you
```

2)

```
row_with_max_value <- max(which(df$values & df$group_column=="desired_group"))
```

"row_with_max_value" contents the row number of your data frame (df), in which you find the maximum value of the column "values" (df$values) grouped by "group_column".
If "group_column" is not of type character, remove the quotes and use the corresponding text format.

If you need the value, than

```
df$values[row_with_max_value]
```

Probably it is not the most elegant way, but you do not need SQL and it works (at least for me ;)