# Finding index corresponding to the maximum value

Tags: r

I found this thread [Find rows in dataframe with maximum values grouped by values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627462/in-r-find-rows-in-dataframe-with-maximum-values-grouped-by-values-in-another-co) where one of the solution has been discussed. I am using this solution to recursively find the row index with maximum quantity. However, my solution is very ugly--very procedural instead of vectorized.

Here's my dummy data:

```
dput(Data)

structure(list(Order_Year = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002), Ship_Year = c(1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, NA, 1997, NA, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, NA, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000), Yen = c(202598.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2365901.62, 
627206.75998, 531087.43, 122167.02, 143855.55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 53650.389998, 
17708416.3198, 98196.4, 31389, 0), Units = c(37, 1, 8, 5, 8, 
8, 730, 99, 91, 195, 259, 4, 1, 3, 3, 53, 3844, 142, 63, 27)), .Names = c("Order_Year", 
"Ship_Year", "Yen", "Units"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to find out the `Ship_Year` for which `Yen` and `Units` are maximum for a given `Order_Year`.

Here's what I tried:

```
a<-do.call("rbind", by(Data, Data$Order_Year, function(x) x[which.max(x$Yen), ]))
rownames(a)<-NULL
a$Yen<-NULL
a$Units<-NULL
#a has Ship_Year for which Yen is max for a given Order_Year
names(a)[2]<-"by.Yen" 
#Now I'd find max year by units
b<-do.call("rbind", by(Data, Data$Order_Year, function(x) x[which.max(x$Units), ]))
rownames(b)<-NULL
b$Yen<-NULL
b$Units<-NULL
#b has Ship_Year for which Units is max for a given Order_Year
names(b)[2]<-"by.Qty"
c<-a %>% left_join(b)
```

The expected output is:

```
c
  Order_Year by.Yen by.Qty
1       1999     NA     NA
2       2000   1997   1997
3       2001   1998   1998
4       2002   1997   1997
```

While I got the expected output, the method above is very clunky. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which.max` works well with dplyr grouping:

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% group_by(Order_Year) %>% 
    summarise(by.Yen = Ship_Year[which.max(Yen)], 
              by.Units = Ship_Year[which.max(Units)])

## # A tibble: 4 × 3
##   Order_Year by.Yen by.Units
##        <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1       1999     NA       NA
## 2       2000   1997     1997
## 3       2001   1998     1998
## 4       2002   1997     1997
```

Answer (score 3):

using Base R

```
a1 <- with(df1,
           by(data    = df1,
              INDICES = Order_Year, 
              FUN     = function(x) list(Yen   = x$Ship_Year[which.max(x$Yen)],
                                         Units = x$Ship_Year[which.max(x$Units)])))

do.call("rbind", lapply(a1, function(x) data.frame(x)))
#       Yen Units
# 1999   NA    NA
# 2000 1997  1997
# 2001 1998  1998
# 2002 1997  1997
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Order_Year = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999,
                                     2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001,
                                     2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002),
                      Ship_Year = c(1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, NA, 
                                    1997, NA, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
                                    2002, NA, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000),
                      Yen = c(202598.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2365901.62, 627206.75998, 
                              531087.43, 122167.02, 143855.55, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              53650.389998, 17708416.3198, 98196.4, 31389, 0), 
                      Units = c(37, 1, 8, 5, 8, 8, 730, 99, 91, 195, 259, 4,
                                1, 3, 3, 53, 3844, 142, 63, 27)), 
                 .Names = c("Order_Year", "Ship_Year", "Yen", "Units"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 20L),
                 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The edited answer gives the correct solution. Previous aggregate function and the output from it will not work all times and its output matching with your expected results is coincidental. Hope this helps without any package

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Data)`), grouped by 'Order_Year', we get the index of the maximum value of 'Yen', 'Units' with `match`, subset the corresponding values of 'Ship_Year' based on that index to return the summarised output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[,.(by.Yen = Ship_Year[match(max(Yen), Yen)],
        by.Units = Ship_Year[match(max(Units), Units)]) , Order_Year]
#   Order_Year by.Yen by.Units
#1:       1999     NA       NA
#2:       2000   1997     1997
#3:       2001   1998     1998
#4:       2002   1997     1997
```

---

If there are many columns, instead of doing this separately, we can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, grouped by 'Order_Year', loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) to get the index of maximum value, `unlist` the `list` output, subset the 'Ship_Year' based on that index, convert to `list` (`as.list`) and set the names of the columns to 'by.Yen' and 'by.Units'

```
setnames(setDT(Data)[,  as.list(Ship_Year[unlist(lapply(.SD, 
  which.max))]), Order_Year, .SDcols = c("Yen", "Units")], 
                2:3, c("by.Yen", "by.Units"))[]
#    Order_Year by.Yen by.Units
#1:       1999     NA       NA
#2:       2000   1997     1997
#3:       2001   1998     1998
#4:       2002   1997     1997
```

Comment: @akrun- thanks so much for you help. Do you mind explaining the steps? I tried executing your code, but couldn't really understand it.

Comment: @watchtower I updated with the explanation.  Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your help. I thought of going with Alistaire's answer as an answer because of its simplicity. I hope you understand.